# Get all products of a category only - without products of its child categories

Tags: product-collection, collection-filtering, category-products

I'm trying to get all products of a certain category. Unfortunately I always get not only all products of the category but also all products from its child categories. What am I doing wrong?

For example I'm working with following code snippet:

```
$catId = 160;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
var_dump( $product->getId() );
}
```

Above category (ID 160) contains 17 products but I get 51 products. If I look these up I see that all these products are assigned to one of the child categories of category ID 160. Sometimes even a sub-sub-category of #160.

Ran a full reindex - didn't help. Caches are all disabled.
Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself.

```
$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
    ->load();
```

you can also use for more than one category as bellow:

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: The first code snippet gives me the same result (all products of child categories). But the second one works for me!!! I'm happy to get it fixed now but I'm also wondering why the first one does not work. It should though! If anyone has any idea why it does not work - please share! @Denish Thank you so much for your post!

Comment: if you are happy with my answer than accept it so this can help to other our buddies also. and once again i welcomes you buddy.

Comment: Figured it out myself. what is this?

Comment: ok buddy wel done...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, it might help you out:

```
/**
 * If you want to display products from current category
 */ 
$category = Mage::registry('current_category'); 

/**
 * If you want to display products from any specific category
 */ 
$categoryId = 10;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

/**
 * Getting product collection for a particular category 
 */
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2);

/**
 * Applying status and visibility filter to the product collection
 * i.e. only fetching visible and enabled products
 */
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($prodCollection);    

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($prodCollection); 

/** 
 * Printing category and products name
 */ 
echo '<strong>'.$category->getName().'</strong><br />';
foreach ($prodCollection as $val) {
    echo $val->getName() . '<br />';
}
```

This is how level value you need to use:

0 - Root of all roots (not visible in the backend)

1 - Catalog Root

2 - top level categories

3+ - go lower in the category tree

Comment: Thanks. But same result

Comment: @Phil Please try edited answer

Answer (score 0):

> make sure is Anchor selected as "Yes" for category #160

[image: make sure is Anchor selected as "Yes" for category #160]

```
$catId = 160;
$category   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents()
    ->addUrlRewrite($category->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump( $product->getId() );
}
```